# Close and reopen HTML tags with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm pretty sure this isn't as easy as I wish, but looking for confirmation.

I want to replace an image with a closing div, the image, and the re-opened div.

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/fdCu5/1/

At the end of the day I want to take HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="constrained">
        <p>Hello hello</p>
        <img src="http://www.nicenicejpg.com/400/100">
        <p>Some more text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and make it look like this:

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="constrained">
        <p>Hello hello</p>
    </div>

    <img src="http://www.nicenicejpg.com/400/100">

    <div class="constrained">
      <p>Some more text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do I need to go up a level and work with it's parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/fdCu5/4/

```
// get reference to the image
var img = $('img')
// get reference to the parent object
var parent = img.parent()
// clone and store parent (should have all same classes and attributes etc...)
var dolly = parent.clone()
// empty the clone
dolly.html("")
// move everything after the image into the clone
dolly.append(img.nextAll("*"))
// put the clone after the parent
parent.after(dolly)
// put the image after the parent (before the clone)
parent.after(img)
```

Advantage of keeping as objects when moving them round, as opposed to just copying as HTML, is that events should stay bound to the objects even after they are moved.

This method does not rely on prior knowledge of the outer container classes/attributes etc...

Comment: Ah, that is even better! very slick, going to implement this

Comment: If you would do me the honor of making me a stack overflow trusted user first - I would be most grateful ;)

Comment: Works great and is very flexible! How do I make you that?

Comment: @Wes - I think you just did :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('.constrained p').wrap('<div class="constrained" />').parent().unwrap();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fdCu5/3/)**

The produces:

```
<div class="post">
        <div class="constrained"><p>Hello hello</p></div>
        <img src="http://www.nicenicejpg.com/400/100">
        <div class="constrained"><p>Some more text</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unforunately its not that simple of markup. I found a solution though, will post below

Comment: Well then why are you posting it as your example?!

Comment: My code does *exactly* what you asked for. If you want a generic solution then you should word your question better and explicitly state that.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another option, here's a merged solution of Billy Moon and j08691's answers. You can just modify the variables as needed to select the children you want to wrap - or you can hard-code it to condense your code.

```
var containerClass = '.constrained';
var childrenToWrap = '.constrained > *:not(img)';

var container = $(containerClass).clone().empty();
$(childrenToWrap).unwrap().wrap(container);
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured out a solution that is pretty flexible:

```
  /*
    Wide Images
  */
  $('img.size-wide').each(function(i,el){
    // cache the element
    var that = $(el);

    // test to see if its a captioned image
    if(that.parent().hasClass('wp-caption')) {
      that = $(that.parent());
    }

    var parent = that.parent();
    var parentHTML = parent[0].outerHTML;
    var childHTML = that[0].outerHTML;

    var newHTML = "</div>"; // close the .constrained div to break out
    newHTML += childHTML;
    newHTML += "<div class='constrained'>"; // open it back up again

    parentHTML = parentHTML.replace(childHTML,newHTML);
    parent.parent().html(parentHTML);
  });
```

Comment: where did `img.size-wide`, `wp-caption` etc came from? Somebody already gave the answer for the question. Which you should accept. this is not the answer for the question, no one can come to this unless others are expected to read your mind.